# how to align tableview column to the largest value text value in adjecent column

Tags: android, xml, layout, tableview

I apologise if this is a duplicate question but I cant seem to find anything relevant on here.

My problem is that I have a TableView:

[image: Current View]

Is it possible to align the second column to that of the longest string value in the first one?

EDIT* The layout design code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Actvities.AddItemActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:text="Overview"
                android:textColor="#ff9933" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_item_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Item Name"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:text="Image"
                android:textColor="#ff9933" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/retake_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"

                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_black_24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:text="Quantity"
                android:textColor="#ff9933" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_quantity"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Number of units"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textColor="#ff9933" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_price"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Price"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:paddingRight="16dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="$" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:text="Supplier"
                android:textColor="#ff9933" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_supplier"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Supplier Name"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="*date will be saved when adding item"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Share you layout code .

Comment: Added the layout code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i get your question clearly , then you need to increase the size of the `ExitText` view so that you can write large string.

you need to change the `android:layout_weight="1"` to `android:layout_weight="2"` . The number actually represent the percentage(weight) of the View. like :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_quantity"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Number of units"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I completely missed that!